# JQuery Datatables plugin and Editor extention column(id) bug

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

***Here is a question about JQuery Data-tables plugin and Editor extension for this plugin.***

---

I'm trying to add some custom datatable + editor to my web page. And I faced one strange problem. My table is exactly the same as **[this](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/joinArray.html)**, but with my database info ofc.

And I'm trying to add some custom search to this table like:

```
//"my_table" is a name of the table var
var. $("#myButton").click( function(){ my_table.column(1).search("Test").draw(); });
```

and it doesn't work at all (doesn't process search).
 
I found, that problem is that .column(id) selector doesn't work. 
1) I tried something like this at first:

```
$("#myButton").click( function(){ var x = my_table.data(); alert(x); });
```

and it's working fine. 
2) Then I tried this:

```
$("#myButton").click( function(){ var x = my_table.cloumn(1).data(); alert(x); });
```

and in that case it doesn't work. I will be very grateful to see any suggestions. 
I noticed that when working with **[this](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html)** simpliest example, that has no editor extention, and a static table content from the html page, both **search()** and **column(id)** API works fine. So I think there is some problem with Editor extention and **column(id)** or idk.

Comment: your last code snippet has a typo in `cloumn`

Comment: you want this handler to run in addition to the out of box search?  A fiddle would help